# Does your educational qualification need to be related to the job offer you get for EU Blue Card?

Tags: germany, blue-card

If I have a job offer in Financial Analytics from Germany eligible for Blue Card, but my recognized degree is Mechanical Engineering, would that cause any problem as an unrelated educational qualification? (my highest degree is PGDM from India which is unrecognized and I have 6 years experience in Financial Analytics)

Comment: From http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html, the employment must be commensurate with the qualification.

Comment: does anyone has ever seen a similar case in Blue Card application? Want to understand what could be done better.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Traveller](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/16118/traveller) in comments and in the [Blue Card FAQs](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html) they shared, it's a requirement to have your employment related to your education.

However, in practice they're lenient towards it. I had almost the same issue and was highlighted by the person who took my interview at the embassy for the National visa that I may not get the Blue card. But when I went for the blue card appointment, they gave me a Blue card. My employment was in Sofware engineering, and there was computer science in one of my graduation courses as minor. I have MBA in finance though.

At the worst, you'll get normal residence permit (Aufenthaltserlaubnis), instead of Blue Card which as far as I know differs mostly if you're married and want to bring your partner with you. But don't take my word and [read here](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/unbefristete-aufenthaltstitel/artikel.599387.en.php) and [here](https://mkenyaujerumani.de/2015/04/16/work-permit-arbeitserlaubnis-vs-eu-blue-card-for-foreign-students-in-germany/) about all the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the job you are applying for must correspond to the degree you have (i.e. they must match)

Otherwise you must apply for a normal work visa and based on your qualifications (practical experience), then a determination will be maded if this conforms to a **highly qualified employment** that is needed.

---

Based on the wording of [§ 19a AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__19a.html) ([English text](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0364))

> 1) A foreigner shall be granted an EU Blue Card pursuant to Council Directive 2009/50/EC of 25 May 2009 on the conditions of entry and residence of third-country nationals **for the purpose of highly qualified employment** (OJ L 155,18.6.2009, p. 17) **for the purpose of employment commensurate with his qualification**, if
>   ...
>   a)  holds a German or a foreign higher education qualification which is recognised or otherwise comparable to a German higher education qualification or

the degree must match the employment.